# Thingworx: Fetch users avatar

Tags: thingworx

I am creating `Service` for obtaining user's avatar:

```
var currentUser = Resources["CurrentSessionInfo"].GetCurrentUser();
var result = Users[currentUser].getAvatarURL();
```

But I am getting 500th server error code. Could you please point me out my mistake and help me fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct service name is GetAvatarURL(), with uppercase.